# NSSavePanel and NSOpenPanel does not work on macOS 10.15 as its out of process like sandboxed app

Tags: objective-c, macos, macos-catalina, out-of-process

On Catalina using NSSavePanel constructor or static object gives error

> eclipse  +[NSXPCSharedListener endpointForReply:withListenerName:]: an error occurred while attempting to obtain endpoint for listener 'com.apple.view-bridge': Connection interrupted.

So what API/hack should be used so that NSPanel will properly in macOS Catalina 10.15?

Comment: Welcome to SO. You need to provide more information including code that demonstrates the problem otherwise people will simply be guessing. `NSOpenPanel`/`NSSavePanel` are core API used by a large %age of apps, if they simply didn't work under Catalina it would be front page news. However since the sandbox these APIs have been known to be sensitive souls, easily upset, and your code and description of the issue should help people help you find why they're misbehaving. Don't try to add information in the comments, edit your question to add it. HTH

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem today in an application that is based on [Kickstart4J](https://github.com/fuinorg/kickstart4j).

When Kickstart4J installs the JRE that should be used to start the application it changes the permissions of the `java` executable to `rwxr--r--`. This change always ended in the error.

By changing the permissions of the `java` executable later to `rwxr-xr-x` solved the problem. I still have no idea why this is working and an explanation of this behavior would be great.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen the same symptom in multiple third-party applications (Microsoft Word and Excel, Avid Sibelius, etc.) as well as my own.  The problem is intermittent; it usually goes away if I close all open applications and try again, and (so far) it always goes away if I restart the system.  In my app, I see the same error message as reported by the original poster here.